# How to make icon and `a` in one line

Tags: html, css, hover

So, I used sidebar menu in my web. At the first, this sidebar just has 100px, and when I hover the mouse to it, it will shows up all the sidebar. this is the image, before and after hover:

My HTML code:

```css
   .sidenav {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100px; 
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 2;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #111;
            overflow-x: hidden; 
            padding-top: 60px; 
            transition: 0.8s;
        }
        
        .sidenav:hover{
           width: 250px;
           transition: 0.8s;
        }
    
    .sidenav a {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1300ms
    }
    .sidenav:hover a {
        opacity: 1
    }


    .icon{
      display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"> <!-- CSSnya di 2691 -->
      <br><br>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
      <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
      <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
    </div>
    </body>
```

all my link menu is hidden when sidebar is not hover, and will appear when hovered. My question is how to just display icons when sidebar is not hover, and display all when its hover, where I use this class:
so its still shows when sidebar not hover and still in one line with the link menu? thanks

Comment: do you want to hide the icons when the side bar is hovered on, and display them when there is no hover?

Comment: I want the icons always displayed, hover or not hover @RimilDey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FontAwesome for the icons. Hope it helped.

```css
.sidenav a {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 37px;
    color: transparent;
    transition: 1300ms;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: arial;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
i {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px !important;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
.sidenav {
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}
.sidenav:hover {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.8s;
}
.sidenav:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7a90a673fc.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"> 
  <br><br>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Home</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Menu 1</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Menu 2</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Menu 3</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Menu 4</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Menu 5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  transform: translatex(-150px);
}
.sidenav:hover {
  transition: 0.8s;
  transform: translatex(0);
}
.sidenav a {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  transition: opacity 1300ms;
  position: relative;
}
.sidenav a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -16px;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <!-- CSSnya di 2691 -->
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
  <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
</div>
```